# Multiple cameras tethering?

Tags: tethering

Sending photos from 3 camera to a laptop either IOS or windows, simultaneously wirelessly, is it even possible?

I have three cameras , a canon G11, a canon 7d and a canon 400d. They all have different lenses mounted on them. I need to take three different types of photographs from a subject by these three cameras. This for skin cancer photography, hence I need a normal photograph of a mole then a macro view of the lesion and then a dermatoscopic view of the lesion which requires me to have three different cameras at the same time to avoid changing lenses which can be quite time consuming. Now I was wondering whether there is anyway to send all the captured photos to a base laptop as I am taking photos. I have bought a wifi SD card for my Canon G11 already but the problem is that I cannot be connected to more than 1 wifi SD card at the same time.

I have read about the CamRanger here but I am not sure whether that is the solution or not? 
I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35862/9161

Comment: Why is it necessary to tether them at the same time. At first I thought this question was going in the direction of needing to take the picture on all three at the exact same time but now I think you are just worried about lens changes. If you are just taking a single picture at a time is it not OK to just swap the cable over or use the SD cards?

Answer (score 0):

Use some EyeFi SD card that support the "[EyeFi Cloud](http://www.eyefi.com/products/cloud)"  Service:

From the website:

> Multiple cameras. One experience.
>
> **Take pictures using any camera** or smartphone you own, **Eyefi Cloud will
>   make them appear as one photo collection**. Gone are days of manually
>   merging together pictures from multiple devices. Eyefi Cloud does it
>   for you automatically.

You should be able to use some **SD to CF adapter**, to use the Eyefi SD card on [**the 7D**](http://forums.eye.fi/viewtopic.php?t=1777) and [**the 400D**](http://forums.eye.fi/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=210) as reported in the linked thread.

***Note: this answer is just a suggestion, I've never tried the EyeFi SD card, nor the EyeFi Cloud service, nor any SD to CF adapter. Do your research before buying anything.***

Also, as suggested by Michael Stum, it may be worth checking whether uploading pictures to a cloud service **is permissible or not** since we seem to deal with medical images.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but one thing to check is whether or not uploading pictures to a cloud service is permissible or not since we seem to deal with medical images